# Does a person with a rugged look and bold voice not fail in a fight?

Tags: streetfight, attack

Does a person with a rugged look and bold voice not fail in a fight?

Comment: In short, no. That only works in the movies. In real life, if someone wants to fight you, they need very little reason to start. Your defiance will invite the fight to happen. So you need to be able to back it up by being ready to fight.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but its safe to say that appearance is only loosely correlated with ability to fight.

Answer (score 1):

No. Appearances do not determine who wins (does not fail) in a fight. There are other factors including speed, bravery, cunning, and deception that may determine the outcome.

A famous story where the apparent stronger (rugged with strong voice) fighter loses is the Biblical story of [David and Goliath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goliath). Goliath is the much larger and stronger individual, but he is killed by David, a smaller, cunning opponent, who slings a stone into Goliath's head. David enters combat without armor or a sword, choosing a staff and sling as his weapons. The expected result of combat between a larger, stronger fighter with superior armor and weapons and a smaller, weaker fighter is that the larger fighter wins. In this case, the smaller fighter prevails using his skill with a projectile.